# What is the meaning of Maarga Dharshan?

Tags: darshan

What is the meaning of Maarga Dharshan? In what context is it used and who is the one eligible to provide this Dharshan?

Answer (score 1):

To word Darshana (दर्शन) has the following meanings

> seeing,looking perceived, become visible or manifested
>
> showing, exhibiting
>
> **demonstrating, teaching**

The word Marga (मार्ग) means

> a way, road, path

and is derived from the verb root Marg (मार्ग्)

> to seek, seek for

***Hence, Marga Darshana would mean to demonstrate a path for the seeker. It is used in the context of spiritual guidance, or guidance for any other way.***

In my opinion, a person who knows already knows the way or has crossed over the (spiritual) path can provide *Marga Darshana*. In this context, a Guru or an enlightened Master.

In a limited context, a personal with knowledge of a specific aspect can provide guidance for that aspect only.

Reference used: [The Practical Sanskrit-English Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/ldpd_7285627_000) by *Vaman Shivaram Apte.*